# ListView tapa a TextView

Tags: android-studio

Veran, tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el cual, tengo un textview junto a un ListView, el cual tiene varios nombres. Cuando pulse en el ListView, el texto del TextView se cambiara al del elemento del ListView escogido.
Pero me encuentro con que el listview se pone encima de la pantalla y tapa al textview.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me encuentro con esto otro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasare el codigo del activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Lista"
    android:layout_width="278dp"
    android:layout_height="332dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.355"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.573">

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Texto"
    android:layout_width="203dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Nombre"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.471"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />
```

Edito:
Por si acaso, pasare tambien el codigo que tengo en Main_Activity.java, por si ahi estuviese el fallo.

```
package com.example.pcx.textos;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{
    String nombres[]={"Paco","Rita","Carlos","Mario"};
    ListView lista;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lista=findViewById(R.id.Lista);
        ArrayAdapter <String> adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nombres);
        setListAdapter(adaptador);
        getListView().setSelection(0);
    }

    public void OnItemSelected(ListView p, View v, int position, long id){
        CharSequence nombre=((TextView)v).getText();
        TextView superior=findViewById(R.id.Texto);
        superior.setText(nombre);
    }
}
```

Aparte, subire un intento en que agrupo a los objetos en RelativeLayout, que es el estado actual.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si usas un LinearLayout con orientación vertical?

Comment: @AlbertoTorre He oido sobre eso, pero no entiendo como lo hago. ¿Un ejemplo, por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad existen varias formas de lograr lo que quieres, pude ser con `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` o cualquier otro tipo de layout, ya que lo pides es un diseño muy básico y con cualquier layout lo puedes lograr. Claro, dependiendo el diseño que quieras hacer, es mejor usar uno que otro.

En este caso para el diseño utilizare un `RelativeLayout`.

Tu problema principalmente es que la posición de los componentes (`TextView`, `ListView`) esta enlazada al layout, que en este caso son los bordes de la pantalla, ya que el layout ocupa toda la pantalla. Y al estar enlazadas al layout, la posición de estos cambia de acuerdo al tamaño de la pantalla. Para que la distancia de los componentes se mantenga siempre igual, puedes enlazarlos entre si y así no importa en que posición de la pantalla estén, siempre tendrán la misma distancia.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hola Mundo"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Lista"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="332dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Texto"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

En este caso el `ListView` esta enlazado al `TextView` mediante la propiedad **`android:layout_below`**, esta propiedad coloca un componente debajo de otro. Para colocar un componente debajo de otro, debes especificar el id de ese componente.

La propiedad **`android:layout_centerHorizontal`** alinea el componente al centro horizontal del layout.

Las demás propiedades utilizadas son muy conocidas, por lo que no creo que haya necesidad de explicarlas. Ten en cuenta que algunas propiedades que puedas utilizar en los componentes son exclusivas del layout que estes utilizando. Por ejemplo, en un `linearLayout` no puedes utilizar `android:layout_below` ni `android:layout_centerHorizontal`, ya que son propiedades del `RelativeLayout`.

---

Para comprender mejor como funciona el diseño de las interfaces de usuario Android, te recomiendo que leas esta [guiá oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html?hl=es-419) (en español), en la que se habla sobre el diseños de los layout.

---

## Actualización

Viendo tu MainActivity veo que tienes varios errores por lo cual la vista de tu aplicación no se muestra correctamente.

Tu actividad extiende de `ListActivity` que es una actividad especial para listas. Bien, si vas a extender de esa actividad tienes que saber unas cuantas cosas.

Esta actividad implementa su propio layout con un listView que ocupa toda la pantalla, si no sobrescribes el layout de la actividad esta mostrara el layout de `ListActivity`, que es lo que esta haciendo ahora y el porque la lista se muestra ocupando toda la pantalla. Para sobrescribir el layout de la actividad utiliza el método `setContentView()`.

`ListActivity` ya posee un `ListView`, por lo que no es necesario crear uno nuevo, puedes utilizar el que ya posee.

Al `ListView` del activity_main tienes que asignarle el id `@android:id/list`, que es el id que utiliza `ListActivity` para enlazar la lista con el `ListView` que ya posee.

El método `OnItemSelected()` que utilizas para escuchar los eventos del `ListView` no funciona, por la razón de que es un método que tu mismo creaste y que no tiene relación alguna con los eventos del `ListView`. Incluso Android Studio (AS) debe de mostrarte el nombre del método de color gris, lo que indica que no lo estas utilizando. El método que debes utilizar para escuchar los evento es `onListItemClick()`, que es un método heredado de `ListActivity`.

El `TextView` lo tienes que enlazar en el `onCreate()`, las vistas por lo general se crean hay. El `TextView` lo tienes que declarar como variable global para que lo puedas utilizar en el `onCreate`, el `onListItemClick()` y cualquier otro lugar de la clase.

AS te debe de marcar error de sintaxis "incompatible types" tanto en el `ListView` como en el `TextView`, ya que no estas haciendo casting de los objetos para convertirlos de tipo `view` a tipo `TextView` o a tipo `ListView`. Incluso, AS te debe lanzar un error al tratar de ejecutar el proyecto.

Conociendo todos los errores y corrigiéndolos tu código debe quedar así:

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    TextView superior;
    String nombres[]={"Paco","Rita","Carlos","Mario"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        superior = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Texto);

        ArrayAdapter <String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nombres);
        setListAdapter(adaptador);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        CharSequence nombre = ((TextView) v).getText();
        superior.setText(nombre);
    }
}
```

#### activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hola Mundo"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="332dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Texto"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Para que puedas entender mejor como funciona la actividad `ListActivity` te recomiendo leer la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) oficial de Android.

Comment: Pues he puesto el codigo que aqui pones pero todo sigue igual.

Comment: Agrega una captura de AS mostrando el código xml.

Comment: ya he añadido una captura con el estado actual.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez he actualizado mi respuesta. Ten en cuenta siempre publicar toda la información relevante del problema, para que así las respuestas sean correctas, de lo contrario las respuestas pueden ser equivocadas como paso en este caso por falta de información.

Comment: Pues muchas gracias. Al fin a funcionado.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva, como marcando la respuesta como **aceptada ✔**, dando un **voto a favor ⏏** o **ambas ✔⏏**, tal como se explica en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio.

Comment: Una cosa, veo que marcas como id para el ListView "@android:id/list". ¿Como apunto a dicha id en findViewById? Ya he visto que R.id.@android:id/list no funciona.

Comment: No tienes que apuntar hacia el id del `ListView` ya que el `ListView` de `ListActivity` ya apunta hacia el.